# Estou tentando adicionar uma ListView dentro de uma fragment ViewPager e me retorna o seguinte erro. Alguma sugestão?

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

> 3-22 17:00:33.850 24857-24857/br.edu.br
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: br.edu.unilab.intercampi, PID: 24857
>                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                 at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.(ArrayAdapter.java:128)
>                                                                                 at
>   br.edu.unilab.intercampi.fragments.FragmentA.(FragmentA.java:23)
>                                                                                 at
>   br.edu.unilab.intercampi.adapters.MyFragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(MyFragmentPagerAdapter.java:25)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:101)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1034)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1182)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1391)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1960)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1157)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1339)
>                                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1044)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5714)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                                                                                 at 03-22 17:00:33.870 24857-24857/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID:
>   24857 SIG: 9

A classe q contém o `ViewPager` e a `List Activity`

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

String [] Viagens = new String[] {"Primeira Viagem", "Segunda Viagem", "Terceira Viagem", "Quarta Viagem", "Quinta Viagem", "Sexta Viagem"};

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Viagens);

ListView listView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    listView = (ListView) container.findViewById(R.id.list_a);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
}


}
```

O Layout da classe

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O adaptador

public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

```
private String [] mTabTitles;


public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String [] mTabTitles) {
    super(fm);
    this.mTabTitles = mTabTitles;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return new FragmentA();
        case 1:
            return new FragmentB();
        case 2:
            return new FragmentC();
        default:
            return null;

    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.mTabTitles.length;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return this.mTabTitles[position];
}
 }
```

Actividade principal

```
public class HorarioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TabLayout mTabLayout;
private ViewPager mViewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_horario);

    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles_tab)));
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

}



}
```

Comment: O resource array quantos itens tem?

Comment: o resource array tem 3 itens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não examinei muito bem o seu código, mas é bem provável que seja na linha abaixo.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Viagens);
```

O método getActivity() vai retornar null por estar sendo chamado quando a classe a instanciada antes do método onAttach(Activity activity) ser invocado pelo android.

Faça a seguente mudança e tente novamente.

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    String [] Viagens = new String[] {"Primeira Viagem", "Segunda Viagem", "Terceira Viagem", "Quarta Viagem", "Quinta Viagem", "Sexta Viagem"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

    ListView listView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        listView = (ListView) container.findViewById(R.id.list_a);

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Viagens);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    }


}
```

Chamar o método getActivity() no método onCreateView não ira mais retornar null, porque o método onAttach ja foi chamado antes.

Pesquise sobre o ciclo de vida da activit e do Fragment existem inúmeros artigos na internet.

Comment: acabei utilizando outro método, mas obg na mesma